# BibTex with apacite is not generating citation call-outs the way I expect them if first author has multiple co-authored papers in the same year

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, apacite

I am using APACite with BibTex and can't seem to get the citations right in cases where a single lead author has multiple papers in the same year.

Problem 1:
Using shortcite I expect a paper with more than two authors to display as: 
(Burke et al. 1999).  However, it is displaying multiple author names, like this: 
(Burke, Curtois, Hyde et al. 1999).

Problem 2:
Where there are, say 3 papers in 2010.  I would expect the citation to include a letter.
(Burke et al. 2010a); (Burke et al 2010b) etc.

Problem 3:
The references list is not displaying entries for a given lead author in chronological (or reverse chronological) order.  I get a 2010 entry followed by 2007, then another 2010 and another 2007 etc.

The following is my bibtex

```
@article{BurkeEtAl1999,
    author = {Burke, E. and De Causmaecker, P. and Berghe, G. V.},
    title = {A hybrid tabu search algorithm for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 1999,
    journal = {Simulated evolution and learning},
    volume = {1585},
    pages = {187--194}
}

@article{BurkeEtAl2003,
    author = {Burke, E. and Kendall, G. and Soubeiga, E. A.},
    title = {Tabu-search hyper-heuristic for timetabling and rostering},
    year = 2003,
    journal = {Journal of Heuristics},
    volume = {9},
    number = {6},
    pages = {451--470}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2007a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Post, G. and Qu, R. and Veltman, B.},
    title = {A hybrid heuristic ordering and variable neighbourhood search for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2007,
    journal = {European Journal of Operational Research},
    volume = {188},
    number = {2},
    pages = {330--341}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2007b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Qu, R. and Berghe, G. V.},
    title = {A scatter search for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2007,
    journal = {School of Computer Science, University of Nottingham, Tech. Rep.},
    number = {NOTTCS-TR-2007-7}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2009,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Qu, R.},
    title = {A survey of hyper-heuristics},
    year = 2009,
    journal = {School of Computer Science, University of Nottingham, Tech. Rep.},
    number = {NOTTCS-TR-SUB-0906241418-2747}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Petrovic, S. and Gendreau, M.},
    title = {Iterated local search vs. hyper--heuristics: Towards general--purpose search algorithms},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Evolutionary Computation (CEC), 2010 IEEE Congress on},
    pages = {1--8}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Qu, R. and Berghe, G.},
    title = {A scatter search methodology for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume = {61},
    number = {11},
    pages = {1667--1679}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010c,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Woodward, J.},
    title = {A Classification of Hyper-heuristic Approaches},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Handbook of Metaheuristics, International Series in Operations Research and Management Science},
    volume = {146},
    pages = {449--468}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2011a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Gendreau, M. and Ochoa, G. and Walker, J.},
    title = {Adaptive iterated local search for cross-domain optimisation},
    year = 2011,
    journal = {In Proceedings of the 13th annual conference on Genetic and evolutionary computation},
    pages = {1987--1994}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2011b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and van Draat, L. and van Ommeren, J. and Post, G.},
    title = {Progress control in iterated local search for nurse rostering},
    year = 2011,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume = {62},
    number = {2},
    pages = {1987--1994}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2013,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Qu, R.},
    title = {Hyper-heuristics: A survey of the state of the art},
    year = 2013,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society advance online publication},
    volume = {64},
    number = {12},
    pages = {1695-–1724}
}
```

This is my tex:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}


\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BBAY}{ }
\bibliographystyle{apacite}



This uses shortcite and I expect it to come out as (Burke et al. 2010a).  Instead I get: \shortcite{BurkeEtAl2010a}.\\\\

This uses shortcite and I expect it to come out as (Burke et al. 2010b).  Instead I get: \shortcite{BurkeEtAl2010b}.\\\\

This uses shortCiteA and I expect it to come out as Burle et al. (2010c), but instead I get: \shortciteA{BurkeEtAl2010c}.\\\\

They only seem to come through correctly if there is a single citation for a given year:\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl1999}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2003}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2007a}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2007b}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2009}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2011a}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2011b}\\
\shortcite{BurkeEtAl2013}\\

The problem with the bibliography is that they are not listed in alphabetical order.  Also, just like the in-text citations, letters are not appearing after the years to signify multiple citations in a given year.
\bibliography{WorkforceScheduling}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:
[image]

Post Edit:
I think this is happening because, although the lead author is the same in each article, the subsequent authors are different.  So Latex seems to be trying to differentiate between the papers by listing out more of the authors until it has a unique signature.  I don't think this is acceptable to the journal because the only examples they have given for correct int-text citations include a maximum of two authors.  Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: The journal has a `.bst` style that does this? Why aren't they sharing it? If not, how are they producing their citations?

Comment: OK.  Yes they have provided a .bst file I can use.  I have configured my tex file to use it with the package "cite".  Had to delete my .aux file to get it working.  According to the comments in the .bst file I am supposed to be able to use the \citet and \citep commands.  But neither of these work.  I get an error "!Undefined control sequence \citet" and also one for \citep.  \cite seems to work, but it gives a long citation.  Not what I need.  Is there something else I need to do?  Another file to delete or compile perhaps?

Comment: To answer my own question I also had to load natbib.  This is now working as expected.  Your response was correct, I was wrong to be using APACite in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine some of the claims you make.

> The problem with the bibliography is that they are not listed in alphabetical order.

Not sure what you base this claim on. It certainly isn't true if you use the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style. Note that sorting is performed alphabetically by *all* authors, not just the first or "lead" author, and *only then* by year.

> So Latex seems to be trying to differentiate between the papers by listing out more of the authors until it has a unique signature.

It's very important to understand that LaTeX *doesn't perform any sorting*. Instead, it's the bibliography style you've chosen that informs BibTeX how the sorting should be performed. As you've noticed, the `apacite` bibliography style does not automatically truncate the lists of author names if two publications share the same year but the author lists aren't identical across entries.

> Where there are, say 3 papers in 2010. I would expect the citation to include a letter. (Burke et al. 2010a); (Burke et al 2010b) etc.

With the `apacite` bibliography style, your expectation is unfounded.

It looks like you shouldn't be using the `apacite` bibliography style to begin with. You may want to switch to the `apalike` bibliography style, and load the `natbib` package instead of the `apacite` citation management package. The following screenshot shows what you would get from making theses changes.

[image]
[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{WorkforceScheduling.bib}
@article{BurkeEtAl1999,
    author = {Burke, E. and De Causmaecker, P. and Berghe, G. V.},
    title = {A hybrid tabu search algorithm for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 1999,
    journal = {Simulated evolution and learning},
    volume = {1585},
    pages = {187--194}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2003,
    author = {Burke, E. and Kendall, G. and Soubeiga, E. A.},
    title = {Tabu-search hyper-heuristic for timetabling and rostering},
    year = 2003,
    journal = {Journal of Heuristics},
    volume = {9},
    number = {6},
    pages = {451--470}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2007a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Post, G. and Qu, R. and Veltman, B.},
    title = {A hybrid heuristic ordering and variable neighbourhood search for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2007,
    journal = {European Journal of Operational Research},
    volume = {188},
    number = {2},
    pages = {330--341}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2007b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Qu, R. and Berghe, G. V.},
    title = {A scatter search for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2007,
    journal = {School of Computer Science, University of Nottingham, Tech. Rep.},
    number = {NOTTCS-TR-2007-7}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2009,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Qu, R.},
    title = {A survey of hyper-heuristics},
    year = 2009,
    journal = {School of Computer Science, University of Nottingham, Tech. Rep.},
    number = {NOTTCS-TR-SUB-0906241418-2747}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Petrovic, S. and Gendreau, M.},
    title = {Iterated local search vs. hyper--heuristics: Towards general--purpose search algorithms},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Evolutionary Computation (CEC), 2010 IEEE Congress on},
    pages = {1--8}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and Qu, R. and Berghe, G. V.},
    title = {A scatter search methodology for the nurse rostering problem},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume = {61},
    number = {11},
    pages = {1667--1679}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2010c,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Woodward, J.},
    title = {A Classification of Hyper-heuristic Approaches},
    year = 2010,
    journal = {Handbook of Metaheuristics, International Series in Operations Research and Management Science},
    volume = {146},
    pages = {449--468}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2011a,
    author = {Burke, E. and Gendreau, M. and Ochoa, G. and Walker, J.},
    title = {Adaptive iterated local search for cross-domain optimisation},
    year = 2011,
    journal = {In Proceedings of the 13th annual conference on Genetic and evolutionary computation},
    pages = {1987--1994}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2011b,
    author = {Burke, E. and Curtois, T. and van Draat, L. and van Ommeren, J. and Post, G.},
    title = {Progress control in iterated local search for nurse rostering},
    year = 2011,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume = {62},
    number = {2},
    pages = {1987--1994}
}
@article{BurkeEtAl2013,
    author = {Burke, E. and Hyde, M. and Kendall, G. and Ochoa, G. and Özcan, E. and Qu, R.},
    title = {Hyper-heuristics: A survey of the state of the art},
    year = 2013,
    journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society advance online publication},
    volume = {64},
    number = {12},
    pages = {1695-–1724}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
This uses \verb+\citep+. I expect it to come out as (Burke et al. 2010a). 
Sure enough, I get: \citep{BurkeEtAl2010a}.

\smallskip
This uses \verb+\citep+. I expect it to come out as (Burke et al. 2010b). 
Sure enough, I get: \citep{BurkeEtAl2010b}.

\smallskip
This uses \verb+\citep+. I expect it to come out as (Burke et al. 2010c). 
Sure enough, I get: \citep{BurkeEtAl2010c}.

\medskip
This also comes out correctly if there is a single citation for a given year:
\citep{BurkeEtAl1999}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2003}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2007a}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2007b}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2009}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2011a}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2011b}
\citep{BurkeEtAl2013}
\endgroup
\bibliography{WorkforceScheduling}
\end{document}
```